# How to remove Sharp Edges on Texture in Libgdx Game

Tags: libgdx, textures

[image: LibGdx Game]

I am making the above Libgdx game but I have come across the problem of really sharp images for my background if I zoom out of the world.

As you can see on the screenshot there are really sharp edges that appear surrounding the texture of the purple background.

How can I make the Texture blend well with the surrounding?

Comment: I do not know about lidgdx but i can tell you that you are placing the background using the world camera(which has view and perspective) instead of using a interface camera. You should place the background using an interface camera, and scroll it depending on the player position. What you are doing is placing the background in the world space, which is not correct.

Comment: @Haruko - you mean OrthographicCamera?

Comment: OrthographicCamera is also a perspective camera, i mean the camera that you are using for the interface, the camera which cover the screen and is not based on world space positions, and has no scale and no rotation. You can use a orthographic camera with world space coordenates, for example to calculate the shadows made by directional lights. Orthographic camera doesn't mean "interface camera", it is just a type of camera which use orthographic perspective matrix.

Comment: Did you try Texture filters? or your OrthographicCamera is too small

Comment: @jpm , I did try Linear Texture filter i.e `skyRegion.getTexture().setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);`

I do not think my Camera is too small because either way the background image has a width of 1024 but my world has a width of 3072. The problem is also that where the background image is starting to repeat again, it has that sharp edge. I wonder how I can hide that or smoothen it.

Comment: @Haruko, yes you are absolutely right, but I am not sure if not doing that will provide a solution. This is because, even without zooming out, where the background image is starting to repeating, there is a sharp visible line.

Comment: Oh i see. I get what you say now, i thought that you problem was that the background was not right when you were moving the camera or zooming. Well it is not that difficult to fix, you should have access to something like this:
https://open.gl/textures You can see there that you can define if a texture should repeat or not. I searched the command for Lidgdx, texture.setWrap(TextureWrap.Repeat, TextureWrap.Repeat); Just use it, do not place X textures.

Comment: @Haruko, the solution worked like a chat. All I had to do was use `texture.setWrap(TextureWrap.Repeat, TextureWrap.Repeat);` as you had suggested. 

You can write a more comprehensive answer so that I can accept it as the right one.

Comment: Nice! :) glad to hear that all worked right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking with Rowland Mtetezi(the post creator), we found a way to solve his problem. The sharp edges were caused because he was using different objects with the same texture for the background, instead of using a wrap texture repeat and use just one object. Then, the solution was to use:

```
texture.setWrap(TextureWrap.Repeat, TextureWrap.Repeat);
```

To repeat the texture through the entire background, instead of placing different consecutive objects with the same texture.